# Rechts vor Links!

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Kleinkinder artikulieren diesen Lehrsatz bereits im Krabbelalter. Ich sah den kreativen Zusammenschnitt der ARD über die NSU. Dort meinte ein Polizist und Freund von Beate Zschäpe, sie solle nicht vergessen Vorsicht im Straßenverkehr zu walten: "Rechts vor Links!". Daraufhin erwiderte die Neonazigruppierung "Rechts vor Links!"; hier bedienten sie deutlich rechtsrassistische Ressentiments.

Da ich selbst Immigrant bin - und die deutsche Sprache nicht vollends beherrsche - würde ich gerne von wissen: kann ich meinen Kindern bedenkenlos "Rechts vor Links" beibringen (Straßenverkehr), oder schüre ich damit neofaschistisches Gedankengut?

Außerdem hätte ich gerne eine etymologische Erklärung; entstammt diese Begriffsperspektive einer rechtsnationalen Feder?

Comment: Ich würde weniger darauf achten, was für Wörter ich verwende, sondern darauf, was ich meinem Kind täglich vorlebe.

Comment: Ich würde Nazis nicht erlauben, sich irgendwelche Begriffe, Symbole oder andere Dinge anzueignen, die ihnen nicht sowieso seit längerem zugeordnet sind.

Comment: So isses: Die in den USA aufgekommene Form der "Political Correctness", in der *ein Wort* per se "böse" sein kann, muss man sich nicht unbedingt zu eigen machen - Das Verbieten der Wörter wird das Gedankengut nicht ausrotten. Andersrum lässt das Wort an sich aber auch nicht automatisch auf das Gedankengut schliessen...

Comment: Hast Du einen Beleg für die Aussage im ersten Satz? Nach meiner Erfahrung können die meisten Kinder nur wenige Wörter, wenn sie laufen lernen und damit das _Krabbelalter_ verlassen. Bis sie mit _rechts_ und _links_ etwas anfangen können, dauert es bis ins Kindergarten-, manchmal Schulalter.

Answer (score 15):

Hubert hat die Herkunft der politischen Färbung von rechts und links bereits schön erklärt, aber im Verkehrsaspekt möchte ich gesondert antworten:

Du kannst Deinen Kindern bedenkenlos "Rechts vor Links" als Regel für den Straßenverkehr beibringen und schürst damit kein neofaschistisches Gedankengut.

Wie jede Äußerung kann man auch diese, wenn man es *unbedingt* will, aus ihrem Kontext reißen, missverstehen und überinterpretieren, aber das grenzt dann schon an Zynismus.

Meine persönliche Meinung ist, und hier widerspreche ich Hubert, dass Kinder so früh wie möglich mit den Verkehrsregeln vertraut gemacht werden sollten, damit sie so viel wie möglich zu ihrer eigenen Sicherheit im Straßenverkehr beitragen können, sowohl wenn sie als Fußgänger unterwegs sind, als auch wenn sie als Radfahrer teilnehmen.

Die Kenntnis von *Rechts vor Links* kann so zum Beispiel dabei helfen, einschätzen zu können, ob es sicher ist, in Kreuzungsnähe eine Straße zu überqueren, wenn dort gerade mehrere Fahrzeuge aufeinandertreffen. Ohne Kenntnis dieser Regel kann das Kind schlechter antizipieren, in welcher Reihenfolge die Fahrzeuge die Kreuzung wahrscheinlich passieren werden und hat daher eine größere Chance, einen schlechten Querungszeitpunkt zu wählen.

Ob das Kind in einem gegebenen Alter die Regel versteht und in der Praxis auch anwenden kann, steht natürlich auf einem anderen Blatt, aber wenn es sie nicht kennt, kann es sie garantiert nicht anwenden.

Comment: Das gilt umso mehr, wenn die Kinder Radl fahren.

Answer (score 8):

Kinder werden wohl kaum ein Fahrzeug lenken, und stehen dann vor einer Kreuzung nicht vor der Entscheidung, ob sie selbst fahren dürfen, oder ob der Querverkehr Vorrang hat. Dann das sagt die Vorrangregel »Rechts vor Links« sinngemäß aus:

> Wenn an einer Kreuzung zwei Fahrzeuge aufeinander treffen, hat jenes Vorrang, das sich rechts vom anderen der Kreuzung nähert. Hat man selbst keinen rechten Nachbarn, darf man fahren. Will aber von rechts ein anderes Fahrzeug in die Kreuzung einfahren, so ist ihm der Vorrang zu gewähren. Nähert sich hingegen ein Fahrzeug von links, so hat es nur dann Vorrang, wenn es ein Zug oder eine Straßenbahn ist, oder wenn es ein Einsatzfahrzeug ist, das sich gerade im Einsatz befindet.

Jedem, der nur zu Fuß unterwegs ist, kann diese Rechtsregel völlig egal sein. Erst wenn man mit dem Fahrrad auf öffentlichen Straßen fährt (was erst ab einem Alter von 12 Jahren erlaubt ist) wird diese Regel interessant.

Für Fußgänger gilt: Auf Schutzwegen (»Zebrastreifen«) hat der Fußgänger prinzipiell immer Vorrang (jedoch nicht gegenüber Einsatzfahrzeugen im Einsatz), überall sonst haben die Fahrzeuge Vorrang. Egal von welcher Seite sie kommen.

---

Die politische Einteilung in rechte und linke Parteien stammt aus dem 19. Jahrhundert, also aus der Zeit, als in den europäischen Parlamenten die nationalistischen Parteien auf den Plätzen in der rechten Seite des Plenarsaals saßen, und die liberalen Parteien Plätze in der linken Saalhälfte einnahmen.

Diese Sitzordnung gibt es heute in vielen Parlamenten nicht mehr (z.B. sitzt im österreichischen Parlament die Volkspartei am rechten Rand, obwohl sie eher zur politischen Mitte gezählt wird. Die deutlich rechte FPÖ hingegen sitzt direkt neben den linken Grünen in der Mitte des Saals, und das Team Stronach, dass politisch in vielen Fragen noch weiter rechts als die FPÖ ist, sitzt links von den Grünen). Dennoch werden auch heute noch Parteien, die eine Politik betreiben, die den »eigenen« Leuten mehr Rechte geben will als den Fremden, als *rechts* bezeichnet, während Parteien, die eher dem Ansatz »wir sind alle gleich« folgen, als »links« bezeichnet werden.

Aber die politische Einteilung in Links und Rechts hat nichts mit den Vorrangregeln für Fahrzeuge zu tun, und beides muss Kinder unter 12 nicht kümmern.

Comment: Ich meine in der Grundschule bereits eine Verkehrsschulung mit dem Fahrrad erhalten zu haben, und mit 9 am Verkehr teilgenommen zu haben. Hast Du einen Beleg für die Behauptung, das sei erst mit 12 erlaubt? Außerdem haben m.W. Fußgänger an einmündenen Straßen auch Vorrang - sie wissen es nur i.d.R. nicht. Rechts-vor-Links spielt dabei aber keine Rolle.

Comment: Der Absatz mit den Rad fahrenden Kindern ist zumindestens für Deutschland nicht richtig. Hier gilt: Kinder bis 8 Jahre **müssen**, Kinder bis 10 Jahre **dürfen** den Gehweg zum Radfahren benutzen. (StVO §2, Absatz 5). Sonst: +1

Comment: Wir haben das auch bereits in der Schule gemacht. Ich kenne noch die Belehrung des Polizisten, der diese Schulung durchgeführt hat. Das mit 12 stimmt nur bedingt, denn ab 7 kann man bereits auf der Straße fahren, wenn man möchte, vorher darf man nicht und ab 12 muss man. Bedeutet, auch Kinder ab 7 kann es schon kümmern. Ist aber irrelevant für die Frage, da rechts vor links ohnehin nichts mit dem politischen Spektrum zu tun hat.

Comment: @userunknown: Zumindest in Österreich: § 65 der StVO (Straßenverkehrsordnung): »Der Lenker eines Fahrrades (Radfahrer) muß mindestens zwölf Jahre alt sein; wer ein Fahrrad schiebt, gilt nicht als Radfahrer. Kinder unter zwölf Jahren dürfen ein Fahrrad nur unter Aufsicht einer Person, die das 16. Lebensjahr vollendet hat, oder mit behördlicher Bewilligung lenken.« https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Dokumentnummer=NOR40065117

Comment: Diese behördliche Bewilligung wird aber 10-jährigen mit entsprechendem Schulungnachweis regelmäßig erteilt ("Fahrradausweis").

Answer (score 2):

Ich persönlich finde das übertriebene "Political Correctness" -- schlichtweg aus dem Grund weil 'Rechts' ein so alltägliches und häufig gebrauchtes Wort ist.

Die einzigen 2 Gründe warum ich mit der "Rechts vor Links" Regel Probleme habe ist

- Kinder verwechseln gerne rechts und links. Auch ich muss mir oft überlegen, was nun wo ist
- Man muss immer darauf gefasst sein dass die anderen Verkehrsteilnehmer diese Regel verletzen. Also nie voll Karacho über so eine Kreuzung fahren selbst wenn man im Recht ist -- Kind auf Fahrrad wird immer dem Auto unterliegen (im wahrsten Sinn des Wortes)

Comment: Es geht hier aber nicht darum, was jeder von uns so empfindet, sondern mit welchen Interpretationen man im Allgemeinen rechnen darf, wenn man die Phrase 'rechts vor links' benutzt. Wird der Hörer das für eine politische Anspielung halten - ja oder nein? Ich hatte als Kind übrigens keine Probleme mit rechts u. links und die meisten anderen Kinder auch nicht. Um Verkehrsverhalten geht es übrigens auch nicht, sondern um Sprachgebrauch und -verständnis.

Comment: Das kommt wohl schlicht auf den Kontext an. Wenn ich meinen Wahlzettel einwerfe und dabei „Rechts vor Links!“ sage, wird man das anders verstehen, als wenn mir jemand schier reinfährt und ich „Rechts vor Links!“ ausrufe.